# Help needed with Eazycap (somagic) PLEASE!

Tags: drivers, usb, software-installation

I followed this guide [easycap-somagic-wiki](https://code.google.com/p/easycap-somagic-linux/wiki/GettingStarted) installing both the Deb somagic-capture and the Deb somagic-capture-tools packages.I skipped both source installs and the "Downloading and building git sources" because they didn't seem to be needed.I was able to get through the "Extracting firmware" and "Performing user space capture" sections without any complications.

I can even pass the video streaming test by running...

```
somagic-capture -n --luminance=2 --lum-aperture=3 | mplayer -vf yadif,screenshot -demuxer rawvideo -rawvideo "ntsc:format=uyvy:fps=30000/1001" -aspect 16:9 -
```

lsusb...

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1c88:003c Somagic, Inc. SMI Grabber (EasyCAP DC60+ clone) [SMI-2021CBE]
```

I'm unable to record anything because there's no file in the /dev folder for the easycap device for me to point VLC or mencoder to. I'm unsure how to fix the problem or what caused it though and after hours of searching google to no avail I am in desperate need of your help.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, this driver is only able to put out video through `stdout`, which is then directed into mplayer or ffmpeg.

This script will duplicate this stream with `tee`, and direct it into both mplayer and ffmpeg.

https://gist.github.com/Brick85/0b327ac2d3d45e23ed33

It requires some tweaking, like replacing PAL with NTSC, if appropriate.